# encrypting password with Java library jasypt digest

Tags: java, encryption, jasypt

I'm working on a group project that will have user accounts. Right now I'm trying to figure out how to encrypt, store, and check passwords. We have already implemented storing the passwords, but not yet encrypting them and then storing them. I'm using the Java library Jasypt, more specifically I'm using their StandardStringDigester class.

My problem is that whenever I digest the same string it comes out differently. The only way I can find to accurately check if a string matches a digested string is to use the Digesters Match method. This method requires two arguments, the unencrypted password string, and the digested one. As far as I'm aware, however, validation should never been done on the client side, and the server side should never see the undigested password. So how do I digest a password, send it to the server, then check if it matches the stored (also digested) password for that user?

Answer (score 1):

To securely store the password, you should understand how and why, you may seach the forum  a little, there are many resources about this topic.

This is one of the more comprehensive: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

> My problem is that whenever I digest the same string it comes out differently.

As far I know the StandardStringDigester uses salt to hash the input. It means the digest comes out randomized every time. It is how it should be.

> So how do I digest a password, send it to the server,

you send the password cleartext to the server, the TLS (HTTPS) should take care if integrity and confidentality

> then check if it matches the stored (also digested) password for that user?

I believe you are looking for the *matches* method:
[matches(String message, String digest)](http://jasypt.org/api/jasypt/1.8/org/jasypt/digest/StandardStringDigester.html#matches(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))  The Jasyp should take the salt, create a new digest with the same salt. If I am wrong, please correct/comment

Comment: Alright thanks a lot, my problem was that I thought it was bad practice to send cleartext to the server. I would like to be sure, cleartext just means unencrypted as the user typed it right?

Comment: @Alex5775 indeed. As soon as you'd hash anything on the client, the hash/digest would become the password. That's why we need https taking care of it

Comment: Once again thanks a lot, just one more question: I'm using Java for this, does Java (specifically sockets) have implementation of the TLS automatically, or will I have to get another library to implement this?

Comment: @Alex5775 if you are creating a web application, the web server will take care of it (if you configure the SSL properly).  If you are creating a desktop application, it depends what protocol are you using. If you are using REST/SOAP (genrally - http-based protocols), it depends on the framework you plan to use. But Java itself can create SSL with no problems (if you get stuck, write another question :P)

Comment: It's a desktop application, but I'm not really sure what protocol we're using, I haven't been working on much of the network stuff. I'll talk with my group partners and figure that out. You've been a lot of help and I learned a lot from the page you linked about about hashing security. I'm sure my partners and I will be able to take it from here with a little research, thanks a ton.